# Отличие слотов и функций в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-faq

Разбираюсь с технологией сигналов и слотов. Я могу подключить сигнал класса A к слоту класса B, а могу подключить сигнал класса A к функции. В чём принципиальное отличие таких реализаций?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ни в чем. Слоты и функции (методы) одно и тоже. Для `c++11` можно сигналы с лямбдами соединять или с функциями напрямую, минуя объявление `slots` и использования макроса `SLOT`.

**Upd:**

Для слотов генерируется некоторая метаинформация – название и подсказка для вызова слота. На этом различие заканчивается и благодаря moc'у программисту такая разница не будет видна :)

Приведу пример подключения сигнала к слоту, функции и методу (работает для `с++11` и `Qt5`):

Тут описывается самый обычный заголовочный файл:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void doooooo();

public:
    QPushButton button;

public slots:
    void foooooo();
    void foooooo2();
};
```

А самое интересное будет в cpp. Там я подключаю сигнал к слотам, методу и функции:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"


void goooooo() {
    qDebug() << "goooooo";
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setCentralWidget(&button);

    // Новая семантика коннектов:
    connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &doooooo);
    connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &foooooo);
    connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &goooooo);
    connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [] { qDebug() << "lambda"; });

    // Старая:
    connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(foooooo2()));

    // Слоты это функции, поэтому можно вручную вызывать их
    foooooo();
    foooooo2();
    qDebug() << "";
}

void MainWindow::doooooo() {
    qDebug() << "doooooo";
}

void MainWindow::foooooo() {
    qDebug() << "foooooo";
}

void MainWindow::foooooo2() {
    qDebug() << "foooooo2";
}
```

---

Больше информации по новому синтаксику коннектов можно найти [тут](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru)

А по сишным лямбдам [тут](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Разве для методов, объявленных в секции `slots`, не генерируется метаинформация с помощью `moc`?

Comment: нет, не генерируется, так как методов нет:). нет методов - нет метаинформации.